# nginx location path matching issue

Tags: nginx-location

I need to match `/admin/foo` as well as `/admin/foo/path` (and `admin/foo/p1/p2`etc), and I need to use a variable rather than using proxy_pass directly, in order to avoid nginx crashing if the upstream server is not available. I have:

```
location  ~ /admin/foo/(.*) {
    auth_basic            "Admin console";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=0s;
    set $target http://admin-console:80/$1;
    proxy_pass $target;
}
```

I've tried a few ways, including having a separate location for `/admin/foo` (without regex), but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this configure, it worked.
Both `/admin/foo/` and `/some/location/admin/foo/` are proxy_pass to `http://admin-console/`.

```
upstream admin-console {
    server admin-console:80;
}

server {
    location ~ /admin/foo/(.*) {
        proxy_redirect        off;
        proxy_pass            http://admin-console/$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but I need to use the $target variable and resolver, as noted in the question. Otherwise if admin-console is down when nginx starts, nginx will crash. Also, I need /admin/foo (no slash) and /admin/foo/path to work (not /some/location/admin/foo).